# If a muggle and a wizard marry, are their children automatically wizards?

Tags: harry-potter, muggles, genetics

Is there any chance that a muggle marrying a witch or wizard will have a muggle child? Is it 50/50, or will all descendants of wizards automatically be magical?

Comment: Of relevance: [Squib](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Squib)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate. Although related, both are asking different things.

Comment: Although the questions are different, the answers on the linked question (and the comments; the answers *could* be improved by adding material from comments) address the genetic basis for magical ability. I'm voting to leave closed

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not necessarily.

There can be muggle offspring from a wizard-muggle couple, but such cases are rare. So, the probability isn't 50%. The magic *gene* dominates in most of cases.

Those muggle children are called [Squibs](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Squib). From the linked Harry Potter Wikia page:

> **A Squib, also known as a wizard-born, is a non-magical person who is born to at least one magical parent. Squibs are, in essence, 'wizard-born Muggles.'** They are rare and are looked upon with a degree of disdain by some witches and wizards, particularly pure-bloods. Muggle-born witches and wizards are descended from Squibs who married Muggles; the magical ability unexpectedly resurfaces after many generations.

Hermione is a descendent of at least one Squib.

Comment: Source for last sentence?

Comment: @PaulDraper http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Granger_family

Comment: @PaulDraper Otherwise, Hermione wouldn't have been magical as per rules. See the quote in the answer: `Muggle-born witches and wizards are descended from Squibs who married Muggles.`

Comment: @SS, which begs the question, where did the first wizard come from? :D

Comment: @SS, ah right, of course. Nothing particular about Hermione, that is the case with every Muggle-born, including her.

Answer (score 3):

**Having a magical parent does not guarantee magical abilities.**

Not only is there a term for the Muggle children of a magical and non-magical parent (Squib), but there are several examples of such in the canon.

- **Gilderoy Lockhart.** Quoting from the “Early Life” section of his Pottermore entry:

  > Born to a witch mother and a Muggle father, with two older sisters, Gilderoy Lockhart was the only one of his parents’ three children to show magical ability.
- **Dolores Umbridge.** Quoting from her Pottermore entry:

  > Dolores Jane Umbridge was the eldest child and only daughter of Orford Umbridge, a wizard, and Ellen Cracknell, a Muggle, who also had a Squib son.

  <sup>(And the award for worst older sister ever goes to…)</sup>

We can also construct an existence proof for Squibs based on what we know about magic. Shortly after publishing *Deathly Hallows*, JK Rowling said in an interview that Muggle-borns must have a magical ancestor:

> **How exactly do Muggle-borns receive magical ability?**
>
> Muggle-borns will have a witch or wizard somewhere on their family tree, in some cases many, many generations back. The gene re-surfaces in some unexpected places.
>
> — [*J.K. Rowling and the Live Chat, Bloomsbury.com* (July 2007)](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2007/0730-bloomsbury-chat.html)

It follows that every Muggle-born must also have a Squib somewhere in their family tree: the non-magical ancestor immediately below the last person to display magic in their family tree.