# Was there ever a "Magical Revolution" in the HPU?

Tags: harry-potter

The [birth rate question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/142320/why-arent-muggles-extinct) got me thinking...

One reason birth rates have dropped in "the real world" is because of the Industrial Revolution. We simply didn't need as many children around for labor any more. And thanks to modern medicine, the children we had lived longer and didn't need replacing as often.

We know through the books and stuff on Pottermore that magic has developed over time (can't cite specific examples, sorry). **But do we know if there has ever been a "Magical Revolution" akin to the Industrial Revolution?**

Comment: i would offer the creation of hogworts as a similar event at least for the british wizards. all wizards in the UK then for the next 1000 years are offered a standardized education, which can foster increased knowledge from the whole country, instead of individual wizards learning new ways to do things, but never telling anyone.

Comment: But what proportion of wizards attend wizarding school? I have a feeling there was a question on that.

Comment: Since I'm not getting any answers, should I broaden my answer to include "or Magical Renaissance"? Or would that be "too broad"? @MattGutting, I think you're right about there being a question about that.

Comment: I suspect the first magical revolution was when first wand was created. But have no proof for that.

Comment: Calling it a "magical Renaissance" would at least make the question clearer. When I saw the question "Was there ever a magical revolution in the Harry Potter universe?" I actually thought it meant some sort of war. I figured maybe it was about if wizards ever tried to revolt against Muggles or the Statute of Secrecy requiring them to hide, or if Muggles tried to revolt against (or kill off) wizards. I was picturing like the French Revolution or the American Revolution, not the Industrial Revolution. The way you phrased it is perfectly logical, but I could see how it might confuse people.

Answer (score 2):

That's not exactly correct. Real-world population trends have (generally) 4 stages. 
[image: Credit to Kurzgesagt]

Stage 1: Death

```
 Lot of babies are born, but poor medicine/sanitation/nutrition kills many
```

Stage 2: Population Growth

```
 Lot of babies are born, and advancements save a majority of them
```

Stage 3: Slowdown

```
 Less babies die, so families have less babies
```

Stage 4: Stability

```
 Birth and Death Rates Stabilize
```

The Industrial Revolution didn't start Stage 2 and then push it through Stages 3 and 4. Instead, it was medical advances like germ theory and nutritional advances such as pasteurization that kick-started the process from stage 1 to 2 and then onward.

In the Magical World, there would need to be a powerful change in the study and treatment of magical diseases and magical food creation. Maybe it was the creation of the Essence of Dittany, advances in Herbology, theory of healing potions/spells or the discovery of the exception of Food for Gamp's Law on Elemental Transfiguration.